# Passing record from element to a view using different models

Tags: cakephp

I have an app were users can add their queries(ItQueries/add). When the IT department views the query (ItQueries/view/1) they should be able to comment/respond to it. What i have done so far is.

In the view of the IT query i have called an element for the IT department to add a response. below is how im calling the element

```
<?php echo $this->Element('/ItQueryResponses/add'); ?>
```

On submit of the ItQueryResponses i would like the action to redirect to the view page of the ItQueris with its comment underneath it.

Here is my code for my element

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('ItQueryResponse', array('action' => 'add')); ?>
<?php echo __('Add It Query Response'); ?>
<?php
echo $this->Form->input('it_query_id');
echo $this->Form->input('response');
?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
```

Here is my add function for the ItQueryResponseController

```
public function add() {
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
$this->ItQueryResponse->create();
if ($this->ItQueryResponse->save($this->request->data)) {
$this->Session->setFlash(__('The it query response has been saved'));
$this->redirect(array('Controller' => 'ItQueryResponses', 'action' => 'view'));
} else {
$this->Session->setFlash(__('The it query response could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
}
}
}
```

Here is my code for the ItQueryResponses view

```
<h2><?php  echo __('It Query Response'); ?></h2>
<dl>
<dt><?php echo __('Response'); ?></dt>
<dd>
<?php echo h($itQueryResponse['ItQueryResponse']['response']); ?>
        &nbsp;
</dd>
<dt><?php echo __('Created'); ?></dt>
<dd>
<?php echo h($itQueryResponse['ItQueryResponse']['created']); ?>
        &nbsp;
</dd>
</dl>
```

Below is my ItQueriesController

```
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

class ItQueriesController extends AppController {

/** index method

public function index() {
$this->ItQuery->recursive = 0;
$this->set('itQueries', $this->paginate());
}

/** view method

public function view($id = null) {
$this->ItQuery->id = $id;
if (!$this->ItQuery->exists()) {
throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid it query'));
}

$this->set('itQuery', $this->ItQuery->read(null, $id));   
}
```

/** add method

```
public function add() {
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
$this->ItQuery->create();
if ($this->ItQuery->save($this->request->data)) {
$this->Session->setFlash(__('The it query has been saved'));
$this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
} else {
$this->Session->setFlash(__('The it query could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
}                       
}
$hrEmployees = $this->ItQuery->HrEmployee->find('list');
$this->set(compact('hrEmployees'));
}

/**OTHER CODE*/
}
```

If anyone can show me how i redirect to the ItQueryResponses view and have the ItQueryResponse underneath the view that would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

```
/** view method **/

public function view($id = null) {
$this->ItQuery->id = $id;
if (!$this->ItQuery->exists()) {
throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid it query'));
}

// debugging
$this->ItQuery->recursive = '1';
pr($this->ItQuery->find('all'));
//end debugging

$this->set('itQuery', $this->ItQuery->read(null, $id));   
}
```

and then navigate to the view and show the output:

would be something like:

```
Array(
   ItQuery => array(
      id => 1
      ...
   )
   ItQueryResponse => array(
      0 => array(
          id =>3
          response => 'some response'
          ...
      )
      1 => array(
          id =>4
          response => 'some other response'
          ...
      )
   )
)
```

Comment: i want the 2 views to show on the same page. That is the ItQueries view on top and its ItQueryResponses below it. Is that doable?

Comment: yes... as long as your models are setup correctly. can you do `pr($this->itQuery->find('first'));` in your controller action and give us a snippet of the output and we can guide you in the right direction.

Comment: if i add that in add function you edited above it doesn't return any array of the parameters. Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: put it in your itQuery controller... not the itQueryResponse controller

Comment: im not sure if i am doing the right thing. I have added it to the view action in the ItQuery and it doesnt show anything.

Comment: oh... make sure you have debugging enabled.. Go to app/config/core.php and make sure the line that says `Configure::write('debug', 1);` is set to 1 or 2... not 0.

Comment: its set to 2. I have edited my code and put in the ItQueriesController. Can you please let me know how to do it?

Comment: Below is the output

    Array
    (
    [0] => Array
    (
    [ItQuery] => Array
    (
    [id] => 1
    [hr_employee_id] => 310
    [comment] => Testing
    [created] => 2013-02-14 11:11:07
    [modified] => 2013-02-14 11:11:07
    )
    )

Comment: Ok so, it's not coming through the model or you don't have recursive set to 1. check your models to make sure you have the hasMany and belongsTo set correctly in your ItQueryResponse model and your ItQuery model. and ensure that you have a fieldname in your it_query_responses table with the name it_query_id

Comment: yes i do have a fieldname it_query_id in the it_query_responses table. Not sure how i must set recursive to 1 and were. Below is my association in my ItQueryResponse Model. 

    public $belongsTo = array(
    'ItQuery' => array(
    'className' => 'ItQuery',
    'foreignKey' => 'it_query_id',
    'conditions' => '',
    'fields' => '',
    'order' => ''
    ),

Comment: can you please guide me on doing this. Maybe i missing out something small in my code

Comment: In my answer under debugging.. I have the recursive line that you need. It will also help to post in your question both of your model's relationships.